# Duvida sobre o uso do npx junto com o npm

Tags: react, npm

Tenho uma dúvida quanto ao uso do `npx`. Quando uso o `npx`  para criar um projeto React, ele usa o *yarn* para instalar os pacotes por baixo dos panos.

Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de usar o `npx`, mas ao invés de instalar os pacotes com *yarn*, setar alguma flag pra que seja com o *npm*, alguem sabe se teria como fazer isso ?

Já tentei:

```
npx create-react-app nomedoprojeto --npm
```

Mas não deu certo, até pesquisei não achei nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria informar a flag [`--use-npm`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3385) usando o comando do `npx`.

Tente desta forma:

```
npx create-react-app nomedoprojeto --use-npm
```

O motivo do `create-react-app` usar por padrão o *yarn* é que ambos foram criados e mantidos pelo Facebook. Acredito eu que seja este o motivo, mas com esta flag, você obriga o `npx` a usar o `npm`.

Se você não queria o *yarn*, uma outra solução seria excluir o arquivo *yarn.lock* e executar o comando `npm install`.